# Having problem when installing packages using npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

Whenever I try to install any package using npm, It throws error saying this.

[Check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQnBg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would attempt to ping `https://registry.npmjs.org/` to make sure you can establish a connection. If you have any proxies installed they do may be screwing with your connection. Unfortunately we don't have enough information here to diagnose network issues.